# Access servers from both side without hairpin router

Tags: internal-dns, intranet, nat

We have a router that does not support hairpin NAT so our app server is not able to be accessed from inside. When using mobile devices we have to either change the app settings or computer host file, and neither options are easy and painless.

However, I think one way to bypass this is to have a internal DNS server that translate any internal access to the web server domain name to its local ip address, so that we don't need a hairpin router.

The question is:

1. Which easy DNS server we can use in Windows?
2. For the given DNS server, how to properly configure it to access the server (say, the server internal IP is 192.168.1.47)?

Comment: The term you're looking for is "split DNS". Searching for that should show you some good how-tos, it can be done with the already provided DNS server from Microsoft.

Comment: Split DNS is one way. IPv6 makes the problem nonexistent, and would be preferred.